# How to make a search engine?

Tags: apache, solr, search-engine

I don't know that I am asking the right question or not, but I'm stuck very badly.  I want to make my own search engine for my final year project.  Also I have done some research on web engines for about a month.  I came across nutch, lucene, solr, xapian, yaCy.  But this was not enough.
I also know that I will need a parser, an indexer, a crawler and a page rank algorithm, but there is so much to begin with and I don't know where to start.

All I need is some kind of tutorial or book where I can find about these terms(indexer, crawler, etc) and how to implement these apache projects step by step and which apache project I should choose to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://blog.building-blocks.com/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you need a search engine have a look at [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com/) a search engine based on lucene with number of features.Read the documentation.

If you are planning to write your own. You are trying to reinvent a wheel.Try to read the book 
[Introduction to information retrieval.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/).

Answer (score 0):

you will need something like solr to perform the search, you can then apply weights to different fields, e.g. meta title.  you need to look at partial document adding and updating.

you will also need something to crawl the sites to create indexed. you could follow the examples in siva post.

If you wanted to write your own, you could use python or and curl the sites. finding all links and firing off more processes to gather the information.

solr
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall to install
then create a schema.xml
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml - think about what fields you need, and which are to be searchable etc.
then you can use apache solr for php or many of the alternatives for queries.

enjoy

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/teofili/apache-solr-crash-course